# Find X,Y Spiral positions by given ID. Hard formula.

Tags: mathematics, javascript, geometry

I need to spawn new villages in my grid-based game map. But i am weak in advanced math.. I need to fetch coordinates by id. These 2 constants can be other numbers. Please help with the function in javascript :)

```
const DISTANCE = 3;
const FIRST_VILLAGE = [0,0];

function get_coordinates_by_id (id) {
  ..
}

get_coordinates_by_id(6) // returns [0, -3]
get_coordinates_by_id(11) // returns [0, 6]
get_coordinates_by_id(2) // returns [0, 3]
```

[image]

And in addition - i want it to return the coordinates without iteration of all the previous positions. I need a formula which just simply does many calculations and without iterations. If i have billion villages, i don't want it to iterate billion times until it finds the position.

Comment: Why do you store the grid in a spiral?

Comment: How else? I dont know the limit of players and i want to place them equally each form another

Comment: From left to right?

Comment: What? that would be bad. I am making a game when every player can occupy grid tiles and spread their territory by occupying other player having grids

Comment: And why does a regular grid stop you from doing that?

Comment: I want them to fight against other players in all 4 directions. Why do you care? Its my idea to keep it like that.

Comment: If you had a regular it would be easy...... Store the grid as a gridcell(,) and then when u add a cell its gridcell(x,y) =new gridcell and for lookups you just use your current or selected locations x,y values to index into the grid.

I use my grid x,y value as the gridcell ID

Comment: Sorry, but I have did a lot already and it keeps like that. I just need to find this mysterious hard formula and i'm fine :)

Comment: Look at answer in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9933724/creating-outward-spiral). This is C++ code but you will the idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for the Python implementation, but according to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/163101/272766n) the code can be implemented like this:

```
from math import ceil, sqrt 
def spiral_strange(n):    
    k = ceil((sqrt(n) - 1) / 2)
    t = 2 * k + 1
    m = t**2
    t = t - 1
    if n >= m - t:
        return 3*(-k),  3*(k-(m-n))
    else:
        m=m-t
    if n >= m - t:
        return 3*(-k+(m-n)), 3*(-k)
    else:
        m=m-t
    if n >= m - t:
        return 3*(k), 3*(-k+(m-n))
    else:
        return 3*(k-(m-n-t)), 3*(k)
```

Comment: Your implementation of this is a lot cleaner than mine, but I decided to post my version as well to my answer, which is based on the other answer over at the Math.SE question. Anyways, this is a really clean way to do it, +1!

Comment: Thanks! It works really good :) Just now had to implement this :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that doesn't involve a very tricky formula: You just iterate and calculate coordinates until you find one. The solution is in Python and could probably use some improving, but it does get the job done.

The spiral iteration code is directly ripped from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/398302/3450269).

```
DISTANCE = 3
FIRST_VILLAGE = (0, 0)

def get_coordinate(id):
    if id == 1:
        return FIRST_VILLAGE
    count = 0
    for coords in spiral(id, id):
        count += 1
        if count == id:
            return (coords[0] * DISTANCE, coords[1] * DISTANCE)

    return (0, 0)

def spiral(X, Y):
    x = y = 0
    dx = 0
    dy = -1
    for i in range(max(X, Y)**2):
        if (-X/2 < x <= X/2) and (-Y/2 < y <= Y/2):
            yield(x, y)
        if x == y or (x < 0 and x == -y) or (x > 0 and x == 1-y):
            dx, dy = -dy, dx
        x, y = x+dx, y+dy

print(get_coordinate(6))
print(get_coordinate(11))
print(get_coordinate(2))
```

EDIT: Another alternative, which is messy but potentially faster would be based on [this  answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/163093/272766):

```
import math

SIZE = 3

def coordinate(n):
    coord = get_coordinate(n - 1)
    return (coord[0] * SIZE, coord[1] * SIZE)

def get_coordinate(n):
    m = math.floor(math.sqrt(n))
    if m % 2 == 1:
        k = 0.5 * (m - 1)
    else:
        if n >= m * (m + 1):
            k = m / 2
        else:
            k = m / 2 - 1

    if 2 * k * (2 * k + 1) < n <= pow(2 * k + 1, 2):
        return (n - 4*k**2-3*k, k)
    elif pow(2 * k + 1, 2) < n <= 2 * (k + 1) * (2*k + 1):
        return (k+1, 4*k**2+5*k+1-n)
    elif 2 * (k + 1) * (2*k + 1) <= n <= 4 * pow(k+1, 2):
        return(4*k**2+7*k+3-n, -k + 1)
    elif 4 * pow(k+1, 2) < n <= 2*(k + 1)*(2*k+3):
        return (-k-1, n - 4*k**2-9*k-5)

print(coordinate(6))
print(coordinate(11))
print(coordinate(2))
```

Comment: Nice. Since this could be run to the end of spiral many times, wonder if it is worth running once and storing a list of items `{id, x, y}` then doing a lookup.

Comment: @lozzajp You mean like  caching system

Comment: Brilliant idea, lozzajp :)

Comment: Yeah caching is definitely a good idea.

Comment: Ah i trough again. I have to call this function quite often. Server-side and client-side. When palyer logs in and If there are 10k users overall, i have to generate a 10k keys object for every player locally to their machine to hold these positions.. Bad :/ I need a fast-working method to fast retrieve coordinate and not use a lot of memory for these

Comment: Is the player constantly connected? A cache on the server could still work and just ask for a request.

Comment: No. the player can connect-disconnect and reconnect to other devices every minute or so. Its a MMO-RTS browser game. I believe there is possible to make a formula for fast retrieving the x/y coordinates without all the iterations. If i want to have a billionth id coordinate, i want this formula to return the result without billion iterations ofcourse :)

Comment: It doesn't look very nice: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/163093/272766